# What's wrong with this attempt to write to a file?C++

Tags: c++

This isn't working for some reason.. Following my textbook I'm pretty sure.

```
void write(string s) {
    cout << "\ntype filename";
    string filename;
    scanf("%s", &filename);
    FILE *outfpt; //new file  
    outfpt = fopen(filename.c_str(), "w");
    printf("Address of file is %p\n", outfpt);

    fprintf(outfpt, "%s", s.c_str());
    fclose(outfpt);

}
```

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure that your textbook does not tell you to use `scanf()` with a `std::string`. Any such textbook should be returned as defective.

Comment: You really need to get a handle on what C is and what C++ is because you can't just mix and match it like this.

Comment: well the textbook is called c/c++

Comment: @DZD, put it in the bin where it belongs. It started wrong *at the title*. C and C++ are different languages, and mashing them together is a source of confusion and error.

Comment: Starting to see that now i guess. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`scanf("%s", &filename);` is what's wrong. `scanf` and its kin can only be used with built in types (`std::string`, despite being standard, is not built in like an `int`).

If you want to accept a simple string as input, try `cin >> filename;`

Comment: @DZD, it definitely should

Comment: I'm using  getline(cin, filename);
and fprintf(outfpt, "%s", s.c_str()); and it's not working

Comment: I recommend using `std::ofstream` for writing to files.  You can use the operator << to output a std::string to the file.  Simple.  No conversions required.

Comment: @DZD, Did the file open successfully? Try echoing `filename` to see it's inputed correctly, check the file is actually opened, and read up on [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

Like others mentioned you should use `cin` for input. But if you have to use `scanf` then there is a way to store the result from `scanf` into a `std::string`

```
std::string filename(100, '  ');
 If (1  == scan("℅*s", &filename[0], filename.size() ) ) 
   { //.....
    }
```

But here a buffer overflow can occur. So use it only if you know the size of string beforehand so that overflow doesn't occur.